# How to get all email addresses for each checkbox that is check with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 divs with forms inside of them and I need to get all the email inputs, that have a checkbox checked, inside that form. Below is a sample of each html block, I have 10 in total.

```
    <form id="realtor10">
            <input id="chckbox" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="10" /> 
        <div id="realtor10">

            <div id="realtor10image"><img src="wp-content/themes/top10realtors/_image.jpg" alt="realtor10image" /></div>
            <div id="rightarea">
                <div id="realtor10logo"><img src="wp-content/themes/top10realtors/_logo.jpg" alt="realtor10logo" width="200" height="100" /></div>
                <div id="realtor10name">Realtor #10</div>
                <div id="realtor10email"><a href="#">(your email address here)</a></div>
                <div id="realtor10phone">(your phone number here)</div>
            </div>  
        </div>  
</form>
```

My goal is to be able to send an email to each email address that has, it's checkbox checked.

Comment: Will the user be submitting that form? If so, then you validate the form upon submission. If no, then how are you going to get that data to the database or wherever you are storing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the email addresses are entered into form fields that end with the string `email`:

```
var emailArray = [];
$('input:text[name$="email"]:checked').each(
    function(){
        emailArray.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Bear in mind that this will still need validating (ideally client *and* server-side, but, certainly server-side prior to storage in the database) and submission to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = $("input:checked").parent().children(div[id=*"email"])
```

then, for each element in this array, you can easily call the .text() to get the email address

i think there are other solutions. You can also find those useful exemples in jquery api